# What is the correct type hint for a class pointer?

Tags: python, mypy

I am not sure if *class pointer* is the right term in python but I am looking for the adequate type hint in this minimalistic example:

```
class AnotherClass:
    some_var=5

class SomeClass:
    def some_function(self, model: AnotherClass) -> AnotherClass:
        return model()
```

When I typecheck the above snippet with mypy, the following error is thrown:

> some_dir/some_file.py:6: error: "AnotherClass" not callable

**So:** What is the adequate type hint for the model parameter in this case?

The following removes the mypy error but it doesn't seem right..

```
def some_function(self, model: Callable[..., AnotherClass]) -> AnotherClass:
    return model()
```

Comment: `Callable[..., AnotherClass]` is actually a better solution than `Type[AnotherClass]` if you only want to construct the class. In your case, you'd even want `Callable[[], AnotherClass]` since you expect `__init__` to take no args.

Comment: @MarioIshac could you elaborate on that? Why is it better? The referenced question does not include this solution.

Comment: `Callable[..., AnotherClass]` and `Type[AnotherClass]` are equally (not) typesafe because both allow arguments to be passed that violate the `__init__` signature. Former throws away type safety purposely (with the `...`), latter allows subclasses which have different `__init__` signatures than `AnotherClass`. `Callable[[], AnotherClass]` is the only type safe option because it only allows `AnotherClass` or a subclass of it with 0 parameters in `__init__` (excluding `self`).

Comment: See this: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=2fd9bcfcccebcf7d18cd8e5f2e5c5afc. Only `take_3` is caught by `mypy` (because it is most type safe), despite all three failing at runtime since no `a` is being passed to the `__init__` of `SubAnotherClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [`Type[AnotherClass]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) as you are passing in the class itself, not an instance of that class.

> A variable annotated with C may accept a value of type C. In contrast, a variable annotated with Type[C] may accept values that are classes themselves – specifically, it will accept the class object of C.

Comment: yep, that seems right :) thank you!